# How to select specific eid in the table without disrupting the table arrangement in mysql

Tags: mysql

I can't select eid=1 in the table. I want to select only eid=1

I tried some code attached.

```
SELECT t1.t1_days,t2.eid,t2.t2_days,t2.timein,t2.timeout
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t1_days = t2.t2_days
ORDER by t1.t1_days
```

The result:
[image: result]

When I tried the below query, only 2 rows are selected.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t1_days = t2.t2_days
LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.eid ='1'
WHERE t2.eid='1'
ORDER by t1.t1_days
```

[image]

expected output:
without the highlight

[image: without the higlight data]

Comment: There appear to be only 2 rows where eid = 1 - without seeing sample data from all 3 tables it's not going to be easy to resolve your problem.AND what do you mean by without disrupting the table arrangement?

Comment: hi i only want to select eid=1 see the eid column. i also want to apper all data in t1_days column. because eid is equivalent to an employee so i want to select data from 1 employee

Comment: Sample data would help clarify,

Comment: what i mean about disrupting is i want to select the same in the picture without the eid=2 because that is not the same employee as eid=1

Comment: please see additional pic

Comment: hi i edited my post

Comment: So the question really is show me the days eid =1 worked/not worked, Where table 1 contains all the possible days and table2 contains the actual days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t,t2;
create table t(day int);
insert into t select id from dates where id < 31;

create table t2 (eid int,day int);
insert into t2 values (1,16),(2,10),(1,30);

drop table if exists t,t2;
create table t(day int);
insert into t select id from dates where id < 31;

create table t2 (eid int,day int);
insert into t2 values (1,16),(2,10),(1,30);

select s.day ,s.emp_no, t2.eid,
        case when t2.day = s.day then t2.day
            else null
        end as worked_notworked
from
(
select emp_no,t.day from employees  cross join t where emp_no = 1
) s 
left join t2 on t2.eid = s.emp_no and s.day = t2.day
order by s.day;
```

Where t contains possible days, t2 contains actual days. The sub query s associates all employees with possible days and the main query test t2.

```
+------+--------+------+------------------+
| day  | emp_no | eid  | worked_notworked |
+------+--------+------+------------------+
|    1 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    2 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    3 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    4 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    5 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    6 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    7 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    8 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|    9 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   10 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   11 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   12 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   13 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   14 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   15 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   16 |      1 |    1 |               16 |
|   17 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   18 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   19 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   20 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   21 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   22 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   23 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   24 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   25 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   26 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   27 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   28 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   29 |      1 | NULL |             NULL |
|   30 |      1 |    1 |               30 |
+------+--------+------+------------------+
30 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: hi i tried your code i dont know whats wrong but its double the day column two 1's two 2's and so on

Comment: Oops sorry, missed a test in the left join answer has been edited.

Comment: owww no! im not good in debugging lol. Thank you very much :) it works like a charm

Comment: modified answer thank u                                                                              'select t1.t1_days,t2.eid,t2.t2_days,t2.timein,t2.timeout from employee e cross join table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t1_days = t2.t2_days AND e.emp_no = t2.eid
WHERE e.emp_no = 1
ORDER by t1.t1_days